# Extract parent node by filtering on child nodes

Tags: json, jmeter, extract, jsonpath

I need to filter JSON on some child elements and to extract the parent node id.
Part of the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "2da44298-05ec-4bb5-acce-b524ef56328c",
        "attributes": {
        "units": [
          {
            "id": "1492de82-2f36-43bf-b077-5cf54a3f38b9",
            "show_name": false,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "a5d76efa-5b21-4874-a8a5-c9c9f8317ee6",
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "id": "b96c127c-6a4f-4a29-924d-63f0ba55972a",
                    "link": {
                      "url": "#",
                      "target": "_blank",
                        "data": {
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
                    "duration": null
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "dbb7e8fd-aa35-4acc-8ad7-1c7dcd08a6d8",
                      "link": {
                      "data": {
                        "id": "dbb7e8fd-aa35-4acc-8ad7-1c7dcd08a6d8",
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
                   "duration": null
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "8a805cd0-7447-4fac-b4fc-aaa9a2f7e649",
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "id": "d64138b6-5195-48b4-a0f7-b087c5496587",
                      "link": {
                        "data": {
                        "id": "d64138b6-5195-48b4-a0f7-b087c5496587",
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
                    "duration": null
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "392406b1-fa20-413b-a98a-4d1a5b201d8e",
                      "link": {
                      "url": "#",
                      "target": "_blank",
                     "data": {
                        "id": "423498d9-8e0f-41ef-891a-34b078862ce7",
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
                    "duration": null
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "contents": []
          }
        ],
        "text": []
      }
    },
    "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0"
    }
  }
]
```

For example, it is required to extract unit id filtered on contents id `b96c127c-6a4f-4a29-924d-63f0ba55972`

I tried the following expressions:

```
$..data..?(@contents.data.id == 'b96c127c-6a4f-4a29-924d-63f0ba55972a')].id

$..data..?(@contents.data.id == 'b96c127c-6a4f-4a29-924d-63f0ba55972a')].children.id

$..data..?(@contents.data.id == 'b96c127c-6a4f-4a29-924d-63f0ba55972a')].unit.id
```

I need to do this way because of those ids are being got from different responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested [filter operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) to get the parent node, something like:

```
$..data.attributes.units.[?(@.children[?(@.content[?(@.id == 'b96c127c-6a4f-4a29-924d-63f0ba55972')])])].id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter/)